# В чем разница инкрементирования итератора?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно удалять значения из листа по мере итерации.

```
std::list<int> lst;
lst.push_back(3);
lst.push_back(3);
lst.push_back(3);

auto iter = lst.begin();
while (iter != lst.end()) {
    if (*iter == 3)
    {
        lst.erase(iter++);
    }
    else {
        iter++;
    }
}
```

Этот пример работает. Но я не понимаю, в чем разница, если мы инкрементируем итератор при вызове функции и после вызова функции.

```
lst.erase(iter);
iter++;//Ошибка
```

Comment: Функция `erase` делает невалидным все итераторы на удалённый элемент. Здесь `lst.erase(iter); iter++;` попытка инкрементировать итератор на удалённый элемент, что есть ошибка. А здесь `lst.erase(iter++);` итератор сперва инкрементируется, а затем в `erase` передаётся копия итератора на предыдущий элемент, которая после удаления элемента больше не используется.

Comment: Недавно был вопрос с примерно таким кодом: `int a[4]; int i = 0; printf("%d %d %d %d", a[i++], a[i++], a[i++], a[i++];`, сейчас не могу его найти. Там в комментариях писали, что "стандарт гарантирует выполнение постфиксного инкремента до точки с запятой". Разве здесь не тот же самый случай? Вполне может быть, что сначала будет вычислено значение параметра функции `erase`, затем будет выполнена эта функция, а уже после - оператор постфиксного инкремента. Так что, мне кажется, что первый пример тоже содержит ошибку. Надо так: `iter=lst.erase(iter);`.

Comment: @maestro [аргументы вычисляются до входа в функцию](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution#11), так что с `lst.erase(iter++)` проблем нет.

Comment: @maestro они были бы, если бы было несколько аргументов (`lst.erase(iter++, iter++)`), т.к. [порядок вычисления аргументов функции не определён](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.call#8).

Comment: У кого есть доступ к удалённым вопросам, пожалуйста, найдите о чём я говорю. Один участник давал 4 разных примера вывода кода `int a={1, 2, 3, 4}; int i = 0; printf("%d %d %d %d", a[i++], a[i++], a[i++], a[i++];`. Вопрос был не более месяца назад. В комментариях было "постфиксный инкремент", "в произвольном порядке". В одном из примеров получалось так, что оператор инкремента сначала возвратил значение, потом была вызвана функция, а уже потом выполнен инкремент.

Comment: @maestro стандарт гарантирует, что все побочные эффекты, связанные с вычислением аргументов будут применены до выполнения тела функции. Поэтому инкремент не может произойти после вызова `erase`. Вместе с тем порядок вычисления аргументов относительно друг друга является неупорядоченным (_unsequenced_). Для примера с `printf` это означает, что несколько побочных эффектов над одним и тем же объектом (инкремент `i`) являются неупорядоченными, что вызывает неопределённое поведение.

Comment: В [том вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445005) для кода с `printf` в комментариях приводился [неожиданный вывод](https://godbolt.org/z/3ajo379Yr): `1, 1, 1, 1`. Такой вывод получался не из-за того, что якобы разрешено делать инкремент после вызова функции (это _не_ разрешено), а из-за наличия неопределённого поведения. Более того, начиная с C++17, порядок вычисления аргументов становится _indeterminately sequenced_. Теперь аргументы должны вычисляться (включая применение всех побочных эффектов) в некотором, определяемом реализацией порядке.

Comment: Наличие порядка устраняет неопределённое поведение, и результат работы программы [становится более предсказуемым](https://godbolt.org/z/jjn3GaGf9).

Comment: @wololo, спасибо за разъяснение.